# How to highlight text in image using coordinates? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, ocr

I have a PDF and coordinates of every word separately in a JSON. I want to highlight searched text in the PDF using the coordinates.

Initially, I thought I'll highlight the searched text in PDF itself using coordinates. But I couldn't find any possible way of doing that in a PDF.
So, now I am thinking of converting PDF to images and then highlighting the searched in an image using the coordinates.

Does anyone have any idea regarding how to highlight text using the coordinates in an image in javascript?

Comment: One approach you can try is to add annotations corresponding to the coordinates which highlight the text. For example, the LEADTOOLS JavaScript Imaging Toolkit has the [AnnHiliteObject](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/javascript/ac/annhiliteobject.html) which can be created from a set of coordinates and added to a loaded document. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor of this toolkit)